# mypy error: Incompatible return value type (got "Union[bool_, ndarray]", expected "bool")

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a class that looks as following:

```
import numpy as np

class TestClass():

    def __init__(self, a: np.ndarray):
        self.a = a

    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        if not isinstance(other, TestClass):
            raise TypeError
        return (np.all(self.a == other.a))
```

Mypy returns the error `Incompatible return value type (got "Union[bool_, ndarray]", expected "bool")`. According to the [documentation for np.all](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) this function is supposed to return a regular boolean with these types of inputs. Is there a reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of static type checking (or at least, the type annotations given for `numpy`). The `np.all` function returns a `bool` value when called with the arguments you show, but it *can* return other types when called with other arguments (specifically, if you pass `keepdims=True` it will return a one-element array with the same number of dimensions as the original input).

The documentation you linked to shows this:

> Returns: all: ndarray, bool

For the situation you show, you don't actually need `numpy` at all, since you're not dealing with arrays in the first place. Why not use the `and` operator, or the builtin `all` function?

```
def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
    if not isinstance(other, TestClass):
        raise TypeError
    return all((other.a, self.a))      # or bool(other.a and self.a)
```